# Error en transacción C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

durante una transaccion me salta el siguiente error:

**Unable to update the EntitySet 'EmpresasModulos' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation**

Creo que es porque no tengo una PK en mi base de datos, pero no necesito una, asi me queda en mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así estoy haciendo mi código:

```
modulosActivos = Session["modulosActivos"] as string;
string[] modsCant = modulosActivos.Split(',');
int[] modulos = Array.ConvertAll(modsCant, int.Parse); 

 using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = Db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < modsCant.Length; i++)
                            {
                                EmpresasModulos empresasModulos = new EmpresasModulos()
                                {
                                    EmpresaId = empresa.Id,
                                    ModuloId = modulos[i]
                                };

                                Bd.EmpresasModulos.Add(empresasModulos);
                                Bd.SaveChanges();
                            }
                           
                            dbTran.Commit();

                            RemoveDatos();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Empresas");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            dbTran.Rollback();
                            ViewBag.VerError = ex.Message + "\b";

                            return View("Error");
                        }
                    }
```

Cualquier cosa consulten, espero que se haya entendido

Comment: y agregaste una pk, por mas que vos no la necesites? EF la necesita...

Comment: No es recomendable, si lo hago y lo actualizo en el codigo me tira muchos otros errores

Comment: Todas las tablas deben tener un campo id que sirva como llave primaria, investiga sobre el patrón de llaves subrogadas

Comment: Si es una tabla solo de relacion, deberias agregarla o por medio de Modulo, o por medio de Empresa, tipo Empresa.Modulos.Add(modulo) o viceversa, de hecho te deberia de aparecer la relacion en tu variable empresa. suponiendo esta es la entidad de BD

Comment: Pero esto es solamente una tabla intermedia, no creo que necesite llaves primarias, solamente foráneas. Si no se puede por entity framework, de qué otra manera se puede hacer?